# I'm getting 404 error in php

Tags: php, ubuntu-12.10, netbeans-7.3

I made my php project in windows8 OS. It is running well in WAMP in windows8. I'm using duel boot so I started my ubuntu 12.10 OS.  After that I copy pasted same project in /var/www/Day4(My project name) folder. And started apache server using " sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start ". When I'm running simple index page I got this error.

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /day4/index.php was not found on this server.
> sApache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

I want know how to run same php project in ubuntu. I'm using netbeans 7.3 for devoloping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux is case sensitive. You're trying to load /day4/index.php, but the file is on /Day4/index.php. Those are the same in Windows, but not under any Linux.

Comment: I changed project name as day4 and changed /var/www/day4 . Now when I tring to run index.php file I'm getting this error. Where should I changed name? Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /day4/index.php on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost

Comment: what is your configuration in /etc/apache2/site-available/default ?

Comment: Sorry I can't find that path. Can you please tell me the whole path.

Comment: I made folder named www in Home folder and set it's path in the configuration of default and default-ssl files using sudo cords. And copy pasted the php projects to that www folder. So now when I'm running that index file I'm getting                          Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /apple/ on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80